# spring-integration with AWS S3 retry failed "get" file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

We are using spring-integration with S3. We have s3-inbound-streaming-channel-adapter to read from S3. What is happening is that if the "get" fails the s3-inbound-streaming-channel-adapter put the filename in "acceptOnceFilter" and doesn't retry on failure.

Q1. What we want is when the s3-inbound-streaming-channel-adapter "gets" a file from S3 and say for some reason this "get" fails... how do we get the s3-inbound-streaming-channel-adapter to retry this "get" request again for the same file?

Q2. On failure, an exception is sent to default "errorChannel" from s3-inbound-streaming-channel-adapter. Would the Message in the exception contain "filename" that failed?

```
<int:channel id="s3FileProcessingChannel">
  <int:queue capacity="15"/>
</int:channel>

<bean id="metadataStore" class="org.springframework.integration.metadata.SimpleMetadataStore"/>

<bean id="acceptOnceFilter"
  class="org.springframework.integration.aws.support.filters.S3PersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
  <constructor-arg index="0" ref="metadataStore"/>
  <constructor-arg index="1" value="streaming"/>
</bean>

<int-aws:s3-inbound-streaming-channel-adapter id="s3Region1"
channel="s3FileProcessingChannel" 
session-factory="s3SessionFactory"
filter="acceptOnceFilter"
remotedirectoryexpression="'${s3.sourceBucket}/emm'">

  <int:poller fixed-delay="1000" max-messages-per-poll="15"/>
</int-aws:s3-inbound-streaming-channel-adapter>
```

Thanks
GM

Comment: Which version of Spring Integration do you use and why you still use XML config instead of [Java DSL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#java-dsl)?

Comment: @Boris - spring-boot-starter-integration v 1.5.3.RELEASE. And XML works and easily readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `S3PersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` implements:

```
/**
 * A {@link FileListFilter} that can be reset by removing a specific file from its
 * state.
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @since 4.1.7
 *
 */
public interface ResettableFileListFilter<F> extends FileListFilter<F> {

    /**
     * Remove the specified file from the filter so it will pass on the next attempt.
     * @param f the element to remove.
     * @return true if the file was removed as a result of this call.
     */
    boolean remove(F f);

}
```

And `S3StreamingMessageSource` populates headers like these:

```
return getMessageBuilderFactory()
                    .withPayload(session.readRaw(remotePath))
                    .setHeader(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CLOSEABLE_RESOURCE, session)
                    .setHeader(FileHeaders.REMOTE_DIRECTORY, file.getRemoteDirectory())
                    .setHeader(FileHeaders.REMOTE_FILE, file.getFilename())
                    .setHeader(FileHeaders.REMOTE_FILE_INFO,
                            this.fileInfoJson ? file.toJson() : file);
```

When error happened you just need to use that `FileHeaders.REMOTE_FILE` to call the mention above `remove()` and your failed file is going to be picked up from the S3 on the next poll cycle.